# How to merge two files and creating a new file containing all the rows and columns of first file plus a new column with the values from second file?

Tags: bash, awk

I have two files like this:
File1

```
a 23
a 24
a 34
b 45
b 34
b 44
b 1
c 45
c 43
```

File2:

```
a 23 100
a 24 221
a 19 454
b 45 345
b 44 344
b 10 443
c 45 190
c 98 324
```

I want to merge these files to get an output which contain all the rows and columns from the first file plus a new column with the values of the third column in file2 if the first and second column of file1 and 2 were equal otherwise it should put a Zero. An output like this:

```
a 23 100
a 24 221
a 34 0
b 45 345
b 34 0
b 44 344
b 1 0
c 45 190
c 43 0
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: try `grep -f File1 File2`

Comment: @F.Hauri that would output false matches where `b 1` matches `b 10`, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One in awk:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {
    a[$1 FS $2]=$3
    next
}
{
    print $1,$2,((i=a[($1 FS $2)])?i:0)
}' file2 file1
```

Output:

```
a 23 100
a 24 221
a 34 0
b 45 345
b 34 0
b 44 344
b 1 0
c 45 190
c 43 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just loop over it?

```
F1="/path/to/File1"
F2="/path/to/File2"

while read LINE; do
  test -z "$LINE" && continue
  FOUND=$(grep -e "^$LINE " "$F2")
  test -z "$FOUND" && FOUND="$LINE 0"
  echo "$FOUND"
done < "$F1"
```

This is ofcourse inefficient, but if the files are small it might just not matter.

**EDIT**

From the comments I see, that the files are moderatly sized, so we need a more efficient solution: We can keep the loop, but we need to get rid of the  in-loop `grep`. We do this by sorting:

```
# Open and sort the files
F1=$(mktemp)
sort "/path/to/File1" > "$F1"
F2=$(mktemp)
sort "/path/to/File2" > "$F2"

# Get first comparator line
exec 3<"$F2"
COMP=''
while test -z "$COMP"; do
  read -u 3 COMP
done
test -z "$COMP" && exit 0

# Cycle through file
while read LINE; do
  test -z "$LINE" && continue
  # Does the line fit our comparator?
  if [[ "$COMP" == "$LINE"* ]]; then
    # Yes: Write out the comparator and get a new one
    echo "$COMP"
    read -u 3 COMP
  else
    # No: Write out the line with a zero
    echo "$LINE 0"
  fi
done < "$F1"
```

Ofcourse you can skip the sorting if the files are already sorted.

Comment: My files are too big (more tha 70 million rows) so it would take much time, I think.

Comment: @Vpers: In your question the information with the 70 million rows is missing. I recommend not tagging your question with `bash` if you think `bash` is too slow for 70 million rows.

Comment: See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: @EdMorton have a look at (my answer in ***pure [tag:bash]***)[https://stackoverflow.com/a/58042021/1765658], without forks, something quicker than  the one using `awk`!

Comment: @F.Hauri I looked and your script would be orders of magnitude slower than an awk script for moderately sized input files. I posted the timings for even tiny files at https://stackoverflow.com/a/58052543/1745001.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is so similar to @JamesBrown's I wasn't planning to post it but @F.Hauri claimed their shell solution was faster than awk when run against the posted input files so here's the 3rd-run time comparison between my awk script and their shell script:

```
$ time awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2]=$3; next} {print $0,a[$1,$2]+0}' file2 file1 > ou.awk

real    0m0.046s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

---

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/bin/env bash

declare -A fnames=() ; declare -a order=()
while read field;do  fnames[$field]=0  order+=("$field")  ;done <file1
while read a b c;do  fnames[$a $b]=$c                     ;done <file2
for fnam in "${order[@]}";do  echo $fnam ${fnames[$fnam]} ;done

$ time ./tst.sh > ou.bash

real    0m0.062s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.030s
```

BUT the relative speed of execution on such tiny files doesn't matter anyway since who cares if you get the result in the blink of an eye vs 2 blinks of an eye?

When running a single iteration speed of execution only matters on larger files so let's try running both against moderately sized input files generated by these 2 scripts:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{for (i=97; i<=122; i++) for (j=1; j<=1000; j++) printf "%c %d 27\n", i, j}' > file2

$ awk 'NR%3{print $1, $2}' file2 > file1

$ wc -l file2 file1
 26000 file2
 17334 file1
 43334 total
```

and again just showing 3rd-run timing to remove possible cache-ing impact:

```
$ time awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2]=$3; next} {print $0,a[$1,$2]+0}' file2 file1 > ou.awk

real    0m0.065s
user    0m0.031s
sys     0m0.030s

$ time ./tst.sh > ou.bash

real    0m1.674s
user    0m0.890s
sys     0m0.765s
```

then we can clearly see the vast improvement in execution time of the awk script over the bash script. Both scripts produced the same output values.

To understand why the shell script is so much slower than the awk script see the performance part of the discussion at [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) and just google "bash associative arrays slow" or similar.

Note that in addition to running faster the awk script is also briefer, clearer, and more portable so there is zero benefit to writing a script using just shell builtins for this task. The guys who invented shell to sequence calls to tools and manipulate files/processes also invented awk for shell to call to do general purpose text manipulation so just follow their intent for the best results.

Oh, and just FYI @JamesBrown's script ran about the same order of speed as mine for both the original files:

```
$ time awk 'NR==FNR { a[$1 FS $2]=$3; next } { print $1,$2,((i=a[($1 FS $2)])?i:0) }' file2 file1 > ou.awk

real    0m0.045s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.030s
```

and the files I generated:

```
$ time awk 'NR==FNR { a[$1 FS $2]=$3; next } { print $1,$2,((i=a[($1 FS $2)])?i:0) }' file2 file1 > ou.awk

real    0m0.066s
user    0m0.046s
sys     0m0.015s
```

Comment: [ myth busted ]

Answer (score 0):

## Pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) way:

```
declare -A fnames=() ; declare -a order=()
while read field;do  fnames[$field]=0  order+=("$field")  ;done <File1
while read a b c;do  fnames[$a $b]=$c                     ;done <File2
for fnam in "${order[@]}";do  echo $fnam ${fnames[$fnam]} ;done
a 23 100
a 24 221
a 34 0
b 45 345
b 34 0
b 44 344
b 1 0
c 45 190
c 43 0
```

Comment: With posted two input files, this answer is the quicker at this SO question.

Comment: That seems unlikely since you're calling read in a loop (which is slow) and using bash associative arrays (which are also slow) but in any case even if it were true - being the fastest with tiny files isn't useful since any solution would run in the blink of an eye on tiny files. Performance only matters for non-tiny input files and your solution would run orders of magnitude slower than an awk solution for such files. I just ran both and even for tiny files the awk solution is faster. I'll post the results in an answer.

Comment: I posted the timings for even these tiny files at https://stackoverflow.com/a/58052543/1745001 and, on my system at least, your shell script is slower than my awk script even for these tiny files.